# iOS UIPopoverPresentationController positioning issue

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

I'm trying to call a UIPopoverPresentationController from a UIBarButtonItem but having issues with positioning it correctly. Especially after rotation.

Here is how it looks in portrait:
[image]

This is how it looks in landscape:
[image]

Notice where the arrow points to before and after rotation. Also notice how after rotation suddenly the arrow becomes grey (as default) although I clearly stated it to be white.

Here is my implemetation code:

```
self.delegate?.popoverMenuWillShow()
self.vc = inViewController
self.barButtonItem = sender
self.conversationQuery = conversationQuery
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover

if let view = sender.valueForKey("view") {
    self.popover = self.popoverPresentationController!
    self.popover!.barButtonItem = sender
    self.popover!.permittedArrowDirections = .Up
    self.popover!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.popover!.delegate = self
    self.vc!.presentViewController(self, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
        self.delegate?.popoverMenuDidShow()
    })
}
```

I've tried using .sourceView and .sourceRect in order to better its position but there is always an offset in how it's presented in portrait vs landscape. Regarding the color of the arrow, i've tried defining it as white again in viewDidLayoutSubviews but it didn't help.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Hey, have you ever resolved that issue? Thank you